# Automating file downloads with Javascript URLs using Python

Tags: javascript, python, download, urllib2

I was assigned to automate the download of several csv files from a site heavily encoded in Javascript (https://www.quantcast.com/download/plannerCSV?&d0Id=01&sc=1&mr=10000&rs2=-1). There is a convenient 'download' button that prompts the download, the URL of which I found using Firebug:

https://www.quantcast.com/download/plannerCSV?&d0Id=10&sc=1&mr=10000

However, to the best of my knowledge, the URL must end in .csv in order for the urllib2 module in python to read/write it to my disk. Is there any way of obtaining a URL for this file that ends in .csv so I can automate the download using python?

I prefer to use python to write the script, but if there is another approach to achieve this task that is more sensible/straightforward, I would love to know about it. Any guidance is appreciated! Thanks =)

**(edit) to clarify**: The data I'm trying to download consists of a giant (regularly-updated) list, which can be filtered in many different ways based on which checkboxes are checked. The URL changes based on the checkboxes, so I believe the URL may invoke a Javascript call that generates a new csv file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Does appending a dummy GET variable work? For some things -- the obvious one to me is the Google Code wiki regarding image files -- they require a file extension and achieve that by passing GET variables that won't be used by the server. Something like:

https://www.quantcast.com/download/plannerCSV?&d0Id=10&sc=1&mr=10000&foo=.csv

I'd check it out, but I don't have a Quantcast account.

Comment: Hmm the URL works as in it downloads the csv file when I click it, but when I plug it into my script and run it, I don't end up with the same csv file saved on my disk. I think it has to do with the fact that Quantcast updates the files regularly and the URL is not directly linked to the file, but rather calls it from a server.

Answer (score 0):

are those url redirect you ? if yes you should use the url redirection (read header ~ use verbose)
or try save the page at the current url with urllib then renaming to *.csv . you should try that.